# Determine the length and angle of a hypotenuse starting from a rectangle at a different angle

Tags: trigonometry

[Lumber support for Plywood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1utYm.png)
I'm trying to orient a piece of lumber over a piece of plywood as shown. The dimensions of the plywood and the width of the lumber are known. The lumber needs to be oriented and cut as a parallelogram. I have to determine the length of the lumber (*l*), the distance from the end to trim off (*t*), and the angle of the cut in degrees (*d*). I think I can figure out the trim off length but I'm not sure.

Referring to the diagram:
*a, o, h* - is known
*w* - is known
*l, t, d* - is unknown

I need a formula to determine:

- the length (*l*) of the (second) rectangle created from filling out the parallelogram
- the length (*t*) of a triangle created from filling out the parallelogram
- the parallelogram's lesser angle in degrees (*d*)

My math isn't too good and I don't understand Greek characters. I would GREATLY appreciate a reply using something like Excel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diameter $h=AB$ across the lumber.

Purple angle $\beta$ is marked. By the Pythagoras theorem

$$ \text{ length l}= \sqrt{a^2+o^2-w^2}$$

[image]

$$ \beta= \sin^{-1}\dfrac{BC}{BA}-\sin^{-1}\dfrac{w}{BA}=\sin^{-1}\dfrac{a}{h}-\sin^{-1}\dfrac{w}{h}$$

$$\text{trim}={w} \tan {\beta}$$

$$ d= \beta+ 90^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got for you:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kxf3H83sP6BI3BP7CBGj5u3EMs4RGY8z/view?usp=sharing

$$ l^2 + w^2 = h^2 \\
l = \sqrt{h^2 - w^2}$$

Knowing $l$, you can use similar triangles XYZ, NMZ to show,

$$ t = h' \text{ cos}(d) \\
t = \frac{w}{\text{ tan}(d)} \\
a' = l \text{ cos}(d) \\
\frac{t}{a'} = \frac{w}{o} \\
\text{therefore, } h' = \frac{wl}{o}$$

Knowing $h'$ we can solve for $d$, and consequently $t$.

$$w = h' \text{ sin}(d) \\
d = \text{ arcsin}(\frac{w}{h'}) \\
t = h' \text{ cos}(d)$$

I may have made some mistake here having done this so quickly, but this can be easily implemented into excel for calculations by varying $a,o,$ and $w$.